# Python Pandas round decimal using reference rows

Tags: python, pandas

I want to round the number in bid_2 and ask_2 depends of the bid_1 and ask_1. If bid_1 has 4 digit after the dot, make the bid_2 with 4 digits after the dot.

My df is like this:

```
          symbol   bid_1        ask_1     bid_2     ask_2
1222   1INCHUSDT    0.7135     0.714      0.71300000      0.71400000
1092    AAVEUSDT     87.35      87.4     87.40000000     87.50000000
1875     ACHUSDT   0.01405   0.01407      0.01407000      0.01409000
```

Expected Result:

```
          symbol      bid_1     ask_1          bid_2           ask_2
1222   1INCHUSDT    0.7135     0.714         0.7130            0.714
1092    AAVEUSDT     87.35      87.4         87.40             87.5
1875     ACHUSDT   0.01405   0.01407         0.01407           0.01409
```

I tried something like this but it doesnt work:

```
df['digit'] = (df['bid_1'].find('.'))
df['bid_2']  = float(round(float(bid_2), df['digit']))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get number of decimals in a float you can use the following:

```
a = 123.5666
decimal_count = len(str(a).split(".")[1])
```

You can use the same in your dataframe like so:

```
df['bid_2'] = df.apply(
   lambda row: round(row['bid_2'], len(str(row['bid_1']).split(".")[1])),
   axis=1)
```

Comment: I got this error TypeError: type str doesn't define __round__ method do you know how to fix it?

Comment: What are your dataframes's dtypes?  `df.dtypes`

Comment: Everything is dtype: object. Is it correct?

Comment: i have changed dtypes to numeric. and now it works. thank you